Triggering onAdImpression in the AD-Mob in android
What I am doing doing

I have the below code where the AD is Displaying
I am using google AD-Mob
AD is displaying fine

What I am trying to understand

onAdImpression() is not triggered when the view is rendered in the screen instead its triggered when I click the AD, GO to the designated AD and return back to the APP where the AD container is present
Is it supposed to work this way or onAdImpression() should be triggered as soon as the AD is rendered on the screen

@Composable
fun BannerAdView(adUnitId: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val adView = remember { AdView(context) }
    
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            adView.apply {
                setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
                this.adUnitId = adUnitId
                adListener = object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded() {
                        // Called when an ad is loaded.
                    }

                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
                        // Called when an ad fails to load.
                    }

                    override fun onAdOpened() {
                        // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
                    }

                    override fun onAdClicked() {
                        // Called when an ad is clicked.
                    }

                    override fun onAdClosed() {
                        // Called when the user is about to return to the app after tapping on an ad.
                    }

                    override fun onAdImpression() {
                        // Called when an ad impression is recorded.
                        Log.d("AdImpression", "Ad impression recorded")
                    }
                }
                loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    )
}

